# How to bind a dependency property and view model property to one of control in my user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to access property of `MainWindowViewModel` property in `MyUserControlViewModel` I am tying it like this.

I have a `UserControl` which contains one `textbox` and I want to expose `text` property of this `textbox` so I have added dependency property named **"SearchText"**. My user control have its own view model which has property name `commentText`. I want to bind this property to `Text` property of that `textBox`
I have main window where I am consuming this user control. MainWindow view model have property named `Comment` which I want to bind with `SearchText` of my user control.

MyUserControl.xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, Path=SearchText}"/>
```

> here I want to bind Text property to CommentText property of its view
>   model

MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// DependencyProperty for SearchText 
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SearchText",
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(SearchTextCallBack)));

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MyUserControl"/> class.
/// </summary>
public MyUserControl()
{
      InitializeComponent();
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the Search Text. 
/// </summary>
/// <value> The Search Text. </value>
public string SearchText
{
     get { return GetValue(SearchTextProperty) as string; }
     set
      {
           SetValue(SearchTextProperty, value);
      }
}

/// <summary>
/// Search Text call back. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="property"> The property. </param>
/// <param name="args">    
/// The <see cref="System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs" /> instance containing
/// the event data.
/// </param>
public static void SearchTextCallBack(DependencyObject property, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
     var myUserControl= property as MyUserControl;
     if (args.NewValue == null)
     {
          return;
     }
     if (myUserControl!= null)
     {
          myUserControl.SearchText = args.NewValue.ToString();
     }
}
```

MyUserControlViewModel.cs

```
public string CommentText
{
    get
    {
        return _commentText;
     }
    set
     {
        _commentText = value;
     }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<MyUserControl DataContext = "{Binding MyUserControlViewModel}" SearchText = "{Binding Comment}"/>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public string Comment
{
   get
   {
      return _comment;
   }
   set
   {
       _comment = value;
   }
}

public MyUserControlViewModel MyUserControlViewModel 
{
   get
   {
      return _myUserControlViewModel ;
   }
   set
   {
       _myUserControlViewModel  = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: `CommentText` doesn't have to be a normal property, in getter/setter it can simply refer to `MainWindowViewModel` property. All you need is to pass `MainWindowViewModel` instance into `MyUserControlViewModel`.

Comment: Because of some limitation i cant pass MainWindowViewModel to my control. I do some processing on comment in UserControlViewModel. That's why i put those in different view model

Comment: Not to your control, to view model. What kind of limitations? `MainWindowViewModel` already holding instance to `MyUserControlViewModel`, it should be easy to pass instance to child (nested?) ViewModel. Or simply make `MainWindowViewModel` instance globally available or resolvable via e.g. `App.CurrentMainWindowViewModel` property.